# How to change the display of email accounts in Outlook 2016?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

How can I change the display of email accounts in Outlook 2016 (Outlook 365)?

[image]

I have already gone into my account settings and changed **Your Name** and **Account Name**, thusly:

[image]

And yet on the main/home Outlook 365 window, it insists on showing my full email address for each configured email account, instead of a nickname or alias of my choosing. How can I change this?

Comment: It's not difficult to see that half of the bits you have whited out are the same as your username ....

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You have to actually change the Data File name. Not intuitive at all, but that's how it is done. Go into Account Settings -> Data Files -> Setting... - change the NAME of the data file. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In addition to the reply above, I want to add this article for other users' reference: https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/renameaccountandmailbox.htm